# using google apis for jquery ui

Tags: jquery, google-api

Maybe this is dumb, but if I use the google hosted jqueryui api, do I still need to load the individual libraries?  For example, if I want to use jquery ui dialog, do I have to also reference a local path to the js file, or will linking to the jquery ui api load all the libraries itself?

Comment: It should be included. Easiest way to find out is to try to create a dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about linking to the jQuery UI libraries using the Google CDN (https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery-ui), you won't need to bother referencing any other js file for it locally.  Just link to the Google hosted jQuery UI library, and you're good to go :)  Make sure you also link to the jQuery library as well:

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Comment: I think so... :)  Sorry, I'm not that familiar with doing this.  I know I can load the core and ui libraries using that link, but I'm wondering if I want to include a particular widget or effect, will google's link also load all the widgets, or do I have to load them locally?  (i.e., accordion, dialog, datepicker, etc...)

Comment: Yeah, those Google CDN links will load what you need, as far as javascript is concerned.  You will need to load the css files and any image files from jQuery UI from your local machine.  If you download jQuery UI from their site, it will include those files.